# npm run script on a dependency from root level of a node module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-run

I have a node_module `foo`, which has a dependency of `bar`. I want to `npm run postinstall` on `bar` node_module from `foo` directory. Is this possible and how with npm 2 or above?

```
foo
└── node_modules
    └── bar
```